# Cannot install NodeJS legacy

Tags: nodejs

I am using Ubuntu 15.10. I am trying to install NodeJS legacy but I get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-legacy : Depends: nodejs (>= 0.6.19~dfsg1-3~) but it is not going to be 
 installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Why not use KVM or ant of the other linux native virtualization options?

Comment: Have you tried installing with nodesource package?

Comment: Thank you guys. I found the problem that I did not remove NodeJS repository

Comment: Hi, @Magneto10 I'm facing the same error. What do you mean with removing NodeJs repository?

Comment: @rodrunner i'm facing the same issue did you find the solution.

Comment: nope. Finally I did not need the legacy and was allowed to work with the latest node version

Comment: It's officially half way through 2018 and there is no coherent answer to this problem on the internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

end of 2019 now -- It appears nodejs-legacy is obsolete.

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
│Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
│Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
│Package nodejs-legacy is not available, but is referred to by another 
package.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
│This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
│is only available from another source                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
│However the following packages replace it:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
│  nodejs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
│

│E: Package 'nodejs-legacy' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: The nodejs-legacy package is currently not available in the default Ubuntu repositories except for in 16.04.